# Warning: Missing argument 3 for addUser(),

Tags: php, warnings

Warning: Missing argument 3 for addUser(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\MijnPHP\Testomgeving\register.php on line 61 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\MijnPHP\Testomgeving\PHP\functions.php on line 133

Here is the code that is included in my functions.php and used in register.php

```
        function addUser($username, $password, $email) {
    global $connection;
        $passwordmd5 = md5($password);
        $generatedCode = generateCode();
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $to = "test@lol123.com";
        $subject = "Email confirmation code";
        $msg = $generatedCode;
        $headers = "From: test123@hotmail.com";
    //mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
    mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO users VALUES('null', '$username', '$passwordmd5', '$email', '0', '0')");
}
```

This is my register.php file

```
    if(isset($_POST['login_submit'])) {
    addUser($_POST['username'], md5($_POST['password'], ($_POST['email'])));
}
```

So now I wonder how I can get that warning removed, because the code works it puts it into my database but it keeps giving me this warning can someone help me out?

Comment: I am not sure why u r md5ing ur psswrd 2 times

Comment: why you are using brackets for `$_POST['email']` in `addUser`

Comment: Consider a secure hashing algorithm for your passwords like bcrypt(). For its usage check https://gist.github.com/dzuelke/972386.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is on the `md5` function call (the bracket is not correctly closed). You should do it like this:

```
addUser($_POST['username'], md5($_POST['password']), $_POST['email']);
```

**NOTE:** Please read more about why [the MD5 algorithm should not be used for password hashing](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52461/how-weak-is-md5-as-a-password-hashing-function)

Comment: Thank you for this. I know I should not use md5 but it's just temporary for a test site.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing two parameters instead of 3.

Change

```
addUser($_POST['username'], md5($_POST['password'], ($_POST['email'])));
```

TO

```
addUser($_POST['username'], md5($_POST['password']), $_POST['email']);
```

Comment: Thanks for this help!

Answer (score 0):

Addition to other answer if you want to suppress warnings, add below code in your index.php file :

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
```

Comment: Don't suppress warnings for no reason. In this case the warning is identifying a very real problem in your code that you do care about.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are missing `)` in line where you call `addUser`. Because of it your second variable become `md5($_POST['password']), ($_POST['email']))` this is whole considered 1 unit and third parameter going blank
Change line like this

```
 addUser($_POST['username'], md5($_POST['password']),$_POST['email']);
```